# Python: Copy two dependent lists together with their dependence

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy, dependencies, python-3.4

I am stuck with some problem which I guess is not very difficult, but I could not find any answer to it.

I have two lists of objects, each of them containing lists of objects in the other. I would like to copy them both to do come tests and evaluate the results before repeating the process. In the end, I would keep the best result.

However, when copying each lists, the result is, unsurprisingly, not two dependent lists but two lists which do not interact anymore. How can I solve this? Is there some proper way to do it?

Given the two classes defined as follow.

```
import copy

class event:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list_of_persons = []

    def invite_someone(self, person):
        self.list_of_persons.append(person)
        person.list_of_events.append(self)

class person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list_of_events = []
```

I tried to write some simple example of the situation I am facing. The print function shows that the objects identifiers are different in the two lists.

```
# Create lists of the events and the persons
the_events = [event("a"), event("b")]
the_persons = [person("x"), person("y"), person("z")]

# Add some persons at the events

the_events[0].invite_someone(the_persons[0])
the_events[0].invite_someone(the_persons[1])

the_events[1].invite_someone(the_persons[1])
the_events[1].invite_someone(the_persons[2])


print("Original :", id(the_persons[1]), id(the_events[0].list_of_persons[1]), id(the_events[1].list_of_persons[0]))


# Save the original configuration
original_of_the_events = copy.deepcopy(the_events)
original_of_the_persons = copy.deepcopy(the_persons)

for i in range(10):

    # QUESTION: How to make the following copies?
    the_events = copy.deepcopy(original_of_the_events)
    the_persons = copy.deepcopy(original_of_the_persons)

    print("   i =", i, ":", id(the_persons[1]), id(the_events[0].list_of_persons[1]), id(the_events[1].list_of_persons[0]))

    # Do some random stuff with the two lists
    # Rate the resulting lists
    # Record the best configuration

# Save the best result in a file
```

I thought about using some dictionary and make the list independent, but that would imply a lot of code revision which I would like to avoid.

Thank you in advance for any help! I am new both to Python and StackExchange.

Comment: I find it rather unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by "dependent" and "dependent" lists? Could you offer some example of the contents of each list and the corresponding expected contents after the process?

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that after the copy, modifying a `person` in the class `event` will not result in any modification on the corresponding `person`in the list of `the_persons`. I would like them to still be linked together. If you execute the code, you get something like: `Original : 49619744 49619744 49619744` while in the loop, you obtain: `i = 0 : 52093840 52093448 52093448` so the objects are the same (the `id` are different). That is what I mean by dependence. I hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

Since deepcopy makes copies of all underlying objects of the thing being copied, doing two independent calls to deepcopy breaks your links between objects. If you create a new object with references to both of these things (like a dict) and copy that object, that will preserve the object references.

```
workspace = {'the_persons': the_persons, 'the_events': the_events}
cpw = copy.deepcopy(workspace)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This saves me! I tried also with a tuple and it worked well too. I had understood what was wrong, but not how to copy the objects: this does it perfectly well. Thank you!